# XML To JSON Conversion with attributes

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I am trying to convert the XML to JSON.Here am facing challenge my xml have @attributes name as "value" in all tag. while convert into xml to JSON i am using the below code.

```
var xml = "<Message><id value="123"></id><type value="Test"></type></Message>"
var json = XMLtoJSON(xml, ["type", "space", "xmlns", "html"]);
var result = JSON.stringify(json)    
function XMLtoJSON(xml, ignored) {
          var r, children = xml.*, attributes = xml.@*, length = children.length();
          if(length == 0) {
            r = xml.toString();
          } else if(length == 1) {
            var text = xml.text().toString();
            if(text) {
              r = text;
            }
          }
          if(r == undefined) { 
            r = {};
            for each (var child in children) {
             var name = child.localName();
             var json = XMLtoJSON(child, ignored);
             var value = r[name];
             if(value) {
               if(value.length) {
                 value.push(json);
               } else {
                 r[name] = [value, json]
               }
             } else {
               r[name] = json;
             }
            }
          }
          if(attributes.length()) {
            var a = {}, c = 0;
            for each (var attribute in attributes) {
              var name = attribute.localName();
              if(ignored && ignored.indexOf(name) == -1) {
                a["_" + name] = attribute.toString();
                c ++;
              }
            }
            if(c) {
              if(r) a._ = r;
              return a;
            }
          }

          return r;
        }
```

Input XML :

```
<Message><id value="123"></id><type value="Test"></type></Message>
```

Actual Output:

```
{"id":{"_value":"123"},"type":{"_value":"Test"}}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"id":"123","type":"Test"}
```

Guide me where am missing the part to get the expected output.

Regards,
nkn1189

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript. What is `xml.*` supposed to do?

Comment: Hi Str, am using some customized javascript which is specific to my application and it's giving the output without any error. XML.* will give the children node of the XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you think if you do this way will work for you?

put your actual output from that parser to this function:

```
function convertToExpectedOutput(obj){
    var result = {}
    for (var i in obj){
        if (i == "_value")
           return obj[i];
        else
           result[i] = convertToExpectedOutput(obj[i])
    }
    return result;
}

convertToExpectedOutput(actualOutput)
```

So, for your array, hange the convertToExpectedOutput to this way and it will give the expected result:

```
function convertToExpectedOutput(obj){
    var result = {}
    for (var i in obj){
        if (i == "_value")
           return obj[i];
        else
        if (Array.isArray(obj[i])){
           result[i] = [];
           arr = obj[i]
           for (var j in arr)
              result[i].push(convertToExpectedOutput(arr[j]))
        }  
        else
           result[i] = convertToExpectedOutput(obj[i])
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hans Yulian for your immediate response and also your solution worked...

Comment: Hi Hans,i have used the above code here s the observation found in the output. Actual ouput `{"id":{"_value":"312480"},"Item":[{"language":{"_value":"English"}},{"language":{"_value":"France"}},{"language":{"_value":"German"}}]}`

Comment: Hi Hans, I have used the above code and with analsis Array object in JSON is changed to normal object with index
Input XML : `<Book><id value="12345"/><Item><language value="English"/></Item><Item><language value="France"/></Item><Item><language value="German"/></Item></Book>`

Actual Ouput : `{"id":"12345","Item":{"0":{"language":"English"},"1":{"language":"France"},"2":{"language":"German"}}}`                                        
 
Expected ouput :  `{"id":"312480","Item":[{"language":"English"},{"language":"France"},{"language":"German"}]}`